# Extend authentication logic in a Spring Security + Waffle application

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, waffle

I'm using [Waffle](http://dblock.github.io/waffle/) to implement ActiveDirectory single sign-on in a Spring Web application.

I'm also using Spring Security and I followed [this tutorial](https://github.com/dblock/waffle/blob/master/Docs/spring/SpringSecuritySingleSignOnFilter.md) to integrate these libraries.

Now I need to customize authentication behaviour like I've done and described in an old question: [Spring Security: how to map Active Directory users to application users?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27480354/1061499)

I basically need to allow authentication for registered users only and to map AD users to application users.

To achieve this I need to extend some `AuthenticationProvider` and `UserDetailsContextMapper`, but I cannot find anything similar in Waffle implementation.

So, how can I solve my issue? Is there some other approach to add logic in the authentication and authorization chain when using Waffle?